# Adding video call component in react js

Tags: reactjs, agora.io, videocall

I am new to react js. I want to know how to implement Callkit in an already built reactjs  app. Everything is done I just need to apply a module for a video call using agora.io. On button click Incoming video call show on second end user's screen he/she can accept or refuse it. Once call is accept video call started.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this sample app](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-React) for a basic React based video calling application.

With this sample app, you can:

- Join a meeting room with up to 7 people
- Leave the meeting room
- Disable/Enable audio
- Disable/Enable video
- Apply two layouts views
- Hide a remote window

Video Call Documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/index.html

To implement the call invitation, you can refer Agora's Docs:

- [Receive a call invite notification](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/faq/call_invite_notification)
- [Reject call invitation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/rtm_call_busy#sdk-function-description)

Comment: Hello Akshat 
I need one to one video call with call notifications, accept and a rejection option on react js's web app.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hey @NishaNegi you can follow the docs I sent and make the application how you need.

You can limit number of users using [RTM](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/v1.0.0/index.html) by sending messages with user count and kicking extra new users.

RTM will act like a socket connection between all users.